# How to estimate the number of false positives for a given threshold value

Tags: contingency-tables, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

In developing an AI system I am trying to understand how many false positives there will be. The problem is detection of particular features in a set of images so whilst we might know the number of Condition Positive's the number of Condition Negatives would presumably be a function of the threshold value that we use for the detection of the Condition Positives. I know the threshold value we are aiming for (approx. 1 in 1000) and we have an estimate of the total population and the true positive rate. Given this information is it possible to estimate the number of False Positives that we will detect.

Comment: Is not it the confusion matrix question? Look for the cell where your model gives you a '1' whereas the true value is a '0'. After diving this cell's value by the total count in the confusion matrix you get an estimate of Type 1 error rate.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback @AlexeyBurnakov. At this point we don't have a final system working so we haven't tested it at the scale to generate a meaningful confusion matrix. We could simulate the system to generate a simulated matrix but I'm wondering if there is a more direct approach.